# How to restrict android app for tablet/handset using expo?

Tags: android, react-native, expo

I have separate APKs for the same app. For tablets and for handsets.
Also I'm using expo in my project.
Due to android [documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens-distribution.html#RestrictAppTabletTV) I should declare `<supports-screens>` in `<manifest>` like this for tablet support only:

```
<manifest ... >
    <supports-screens android:smallScreens="false"
                      android:normalScreens="false"
                      android:largeScreens="true"
                      android:xlargeScreens="true"/>
</manifest>
```

But it's not good solution, because eject is necessary.
How can solve my problem without expo eject ?

Answer (score 4):

I used [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75907392/6061721) (among others) to help me piece together how to do this. Here is my plugin file to add `<supports-screens>` in `<manifest>`:

```
const { withAndroidManifest } = require("@expo/config-plugins")

function addAttributesToManifest(androidManifest) {
  const { manifest } = androidManifest;

  const supportsScreens = {};
  supportsScreens.$ = {
    ...supportsScreens.$,
    ...{
      "android:smallScreens": false,
      "android:normalScreens": false,
      "android:largeScreens": true,
      "android:xlargeScreens": true,
    },
  };

  manifest["supports-screens"] = supportsScreens;

  return androidManifest
}

module.exports = function withSupportsScreens(config) {
  return withAndroidManifest(config, (config) => {
    config.modResults = addAttributesToManifest(config.modResults);
    return config;
  });
};
```

Run `expo prebuild --platform android --no-install` and check that android/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml now contains `<supports-screens>`. Make sure to delete the generated android folder when you're done setting up your plugin so that EAS does not assume a bare workflow.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately as of 3/31/2021 it does not look like this is supported by expo directly and would require ejecting.

It is tedious, but it is possible to manage supported devices and exclude tablets on the Google Play Console.

https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/7353455?hl=en#zippy=