# Create a Expo Config plugin file to modify Android manifest

Tags: android, react-native, android-studio, expo, android-manifest

I need to create a expo plugin file and call it in app.json for it to add the properties bellow in android manifest.

```
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.touchscreen"
        android:required="false"/>
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.faketouch"
        android:required="false"/>
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.telephony"
        android:required="false"/>
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera"
        android:required="false"/>
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.nfc"
        android:required="false"/>
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.location.gps"
        android:required="false"/>
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.microphone"
        android:required="false"/>
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.sensor"
        android:required="false"/>

<intent-filter>
  ...
  <category android:name="android.intent.category.LEANBACK_LAUNCHER"/>
</intent-filter>
```

I'm a javascript developer using react native Expo, so I don't have the skill set to create the file by my own, I spend the whole day trying to figure this out but there is basically no useful documentation from expo.

Answer (score 1):

I found a similar thread here: [link](https://forums.expo.dev/t/how-to-edit-android-manifest-was-build/65663)

I have added intent-filter following this steps

1. Create plugin folder in your expo project
2. Create js file "example-file.js"
3. In the file I have added following code

```js
const { AndroidConfig, withAndroidManifest } = require("@expo/config-plugins");

const { getMainApplicationOrThrow, addMetaDataItemToMainApplication } =
  AndroidConfig.Manifest;

function addAttributesToMainActivity(androidManifest) {
  const { manifest } = androidManifest;

  if (!Array.isArray(manifest["application"])) {
    console.warn(
      "withWordlLineIntentActivity: No application array in manifest?"
    );
    return androidManifest;
  }

  const application = manifest["application"].find(
    (item) => item.$["android:name"] === ".MainApplication"
  );
  if (!application) {
    console.warn("withWordlLineIntentActivity: No .MainApplication?");
    return androidManifest;
  }

  if (!Array.isArray(application["activity"])) {
    console.warn(
      "withWordlLineIntentActivity: No activity array in .MainApplication?"
    );
    return androidManifest;
  }

  const activity = application["activity"].find(
    (item) => item.$["android:name"] === ".MainActivity"
  );
  if (!activity) {
    console.warn("withWordlLineIntentActivity: No .MainActivity?");
    return androidManifest;
  }

  const action = {};
  action.$ = {
    ...action.$,
    ...{
      "android:name": "com.domain.action.PROCESS_TRANSACTION",
    },
  };

  const intent = { action: action };
  activity["intent-filter"].push(intent);

  return androidManifest;
}

module.exports = function withIntentActivity(config) {
  return withAndroidManifest(config, (config) => {
    config.modResults = addAttributesToMainActivity(config.modResults);
    return config;
  });
};
```

4. In app.json add reference to created plugin

   "plugins": [
   "./plugins/example-intent.js"
   ],
5. Run expo prebuild to see the result

I hope it will help you a little bit.